# java to set a recycle of letters in a certain range

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "Netbeans 8.2";
    String output = "";
    char charData[] = {};

    for (int i = name.length(); i > 0; i--) {
        output = name.charAt(i-1) + output; 
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    for (int i = name.length(); i < 40; i++) {
           output = " " + output;
           System.out.println(output);
    }      

    charData = output.toCharArray(); 
    char last = charData[39]; // von char [39]
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 38; i >= 0; i--) {    //somewhere here must be redone to fix the problem, I know where I get wrong.
        charData[i + 1] = charData[i];  
        for (charData[j] = 0; j < 15; j--) {        
            charData[0] = last; 
            output = new String(charData);
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}

/*
The expected outcome should be like:

2
.2
8.2
 8.2
s 8.2
ns 8.2
ans 8.2
beans 8.2
tbeans 8.2
etbeans 8.2
Netbeans 8.2
 Netbeans 8.2
  ......
   (till length 40)
                            Netbeans 8.2
2                            Netbeans 8.
.2                            Netbeans 8
8.2                             Netbeans 
       .....
etbeans 8.2                            N

*/
```

eventually the last character once moved to right side and reached to the limit of the array range will show up again at the beginning of the left side, which means I should use for to make the rest of the eaten characters keep showing up from the beginning during each recycling. This is the problem that costs me already a whole day and couldn't execute it correctly. I am not familiar with getting string values through 'for' method.

Someone has an idea? really appreciate!
Thanks for stand by! Enjoying coding!

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. your code seems executing perfect, but in question missing what is expected output and what is actual output and more elaboration of the problem

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the ways to do the "loopback" printing. You haven't exactly explained why would you want to do that, so this is as much as I can help you. I suggest reading the in-code comments since they might help you understand some things.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // String name = "Netbeans 8.2";
    String output = "Netbeans 8.2";
    char[] charData;

    // this is unnecessary: you're just copying name into output
    // for (int i = name.length(); i > 0; i--) 
    //    output = name.charAt(i - 1) + output; 

    // adding a whitespace character to the beginning of output
    for (int i = output.length(); i < 40; i++) 
        output = " " + output;

    charData = output.toCharArray();

    // how many times do you want it printed? in my case: 100 times
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
        char last = charData[charData.length - 1]; // save the rightmost character

        // move every character one place to the right, losing the rightmost
        for (int j = charData.length - 1; j > 0; j--) 
            charData[j] = charData[j - 1];

        charData[0] = last; // change first character to what we've saved
        // output= new String(charData); also unnecessary - println can print char arrays as well 
        System.out.println(charData);
    }
}
```